# lost label inside the data when using Kable and for loop function

Tags: r, for-loop, label, kable, kableextra

```
test1 <- structure(list(weight = c(0.2158, 0.799, 0.611, 0.4969, 0.3469, 
1.0107, 0.6946, 0.9415, 1.4008, 0.6192), Q2_1 = structure(c(4, 
4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), label = "How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You or someone in your family will get sick with COVID-19", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Skipped = -1, 
`Very worried` = 1, `Somewhat worried` = 2, `Not too worried` = 3, 
`Not at all worried` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), Q2_2 = structure(c(3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), label = "How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You might experience serious side effects from the COVID-19 vaccine", format.spss = "F40.0", display_width = 5L, labels = c(Skipped = -1, 
`Very worried` = 1, `Somewhat worried` = 2, `Not too worried` = 3, 
`Not at all worried` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double")), group = c("E", "E", "E", "D", "E", "E", "D", "E", 
"D", "E")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using this data to create cross table and also with the question by using for loop

```
library(pollster)
library(rlang)
library(labelled)
library(haven)
    crosstab(
        df = test1, 
        x = Q2_1, 
        y = group, 
        weight = weight, 
        pct_type = "column")%>%
        kable(caption = get_label(test1$Q2_1))
```

The dput() result is and correct after running the code

```
structure("<table>\n<caption>How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You or someone in your family will get sick with COVID-19</caption>\n <thead>\n  <tr>\n   <th style=\"text-align:left;\"> Q2_1 </th>\n   <th style=\"text-align:right;\"> D </th>\n   <th style=\"text-align:right;\"> E </th>\n  </tr>\n </thead>\n<tbody>\n  <tr>\n   <td style=\"text-align:left;\"> Somewhat worried </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 19.16831 </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 47.79164 </td>\n  </tr>\n  <tr>\n   <td style=\"text-align:left;\"> Not too worried </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 80.83169 </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 29.87610 </td>\n  </tr>\n  <tr>\n   <td style=\"text-align:left;\"> Not at all worried </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 0.00000 </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 22.33225 </td>\n  </tr>\n  <tr>\n   <td style=\"text-align:left;\"> n </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 2.59230 </td>\n   <td style=\"text-align:right;\"> 4.54410 </td>\n  </tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>", format = "html", class = "knitr_kable")
```

Now I am using for loop to build the table but somehow I lost the label in the data

```
library(pollster)
library(rlang)
library(labelled)
library(haven)
for (i in colnames(test1)[2:3]) {
      table <- crosstab(
        df = test1, 
        x = !!sym(i), 
        y = group, 
        weight = weight, 
        pct_type = "column")%>%
        kable(caption = get_label(i))
      print(table)
    }
```

"How worried, if at all, are you about each of the following? - You or someone in your family will get sick with COVID-19" this sentence is missing. Does anyone know how to make it appear with forloop?

Comment: Try with `kable(caption = get_label(test1[[i]]))` to tell R you want the label of the dataframe column whose name is stored in `i`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!